# How can I express NaN values in Excel?

Tags: .net, excel

I'm writing a .NET program which generates an XML document that is opened in Excel.  The cell's typically look like:

```
    <ss:Cell>
      <ss:Data ss:Type="Number">123</ss:Data>
    </ss:Cell>
```

But occasionly the value I'm writing has either NaN, DIV/0, or INF.  In these cases 123 would be replaced by that text value and Excel won't open the file because of the text.

I don't think Excel has constants, so I'm unsure of how to handle this siutation, other than put a "-1" value in instead.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Never worked with this before but just a shot in the dark... What if you enclose the above in a IF Condition?

Comment: Try setting the values in Excel, save the result to XML format, and confirm what the value is.

Answer (score 12):

Here are the different error-codes that Excel knows about, stored in XML format:

```
<Cell><Data ss:Type="Error">#DIV/0!</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="Error">#NUM!</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="Error">#VALUE!</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="Error">#N/A</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="Error">#NAME?</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="Error">#REF!</Data></Cell>
<Cell><Data ss:Type="Error">#NULL!</Data></Cell>
```

Only the first two are relevant for your question, but I added the others for the sake of completeness.

> But occasionly the value I'm writing has either NaN, DIV/0, or INF

`DIV/0` maps to `#DIV/0!`. I do not think there is a distinction between `NaN` or `INF` in Excel, they both seem to be expressed as `#NUM!`. For example, both of the following formulas resulted in `#NUM!`, even though the first one is an invalid number whereas the second one is just very large.

```
=ASIN(2)
=EXP(EXP(10))
```

Interesting, tough hardly useful: Excel allows you to enter these literal error values (including all punctuation) into cells on your worksheet without a problem. In a sense, these *are* built-in constants.

Comment: It was useful to me  I prefer to have an Excel-supported constant that represents Not Available… and that's what your `#N/A` did for me, thanks!